# Modify revtex abstract

Tags: revtex, abstract

I'm trying to modify the abstract style of a revtex 4.1 document and am running into problems.  I'm just using the revtex-4.1 style file for a personal project (i.e. not worried about submitting to a journal or similar).  So far if I try to use \renewenvironment{abstract} as in the first answer to this question:

[How to adjust the width of abstract?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151583/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-abstract)

the abstract is formatted how I want, except it appears below the title when I compile.  A minimal example using \renewenvironment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,aps,pra,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\onecolumngrid
    \list{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{.5in}% 
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
        }%
        \item\relax}
        {\endlist}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{Some vagrant}
\affiliation{Some box}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the parameters used by `revtex4-1`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,aps,pra,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-1in\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{Some vagrant}
\affiliation{Some box}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The macro `\frontmatter@abstractwidth` is set by the journal options, so you can override it; the abstract is typeset in a box as wide as stated by `\frontmatter@abstractwidth` and horizontally centered on the page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explanation, this worked perfectly!

Comment: I noticed after the fact this solution appears to have a side effect - in my table of contents sections have been demoted to subsections and subsections to subsubsections.  Is there some way around that?

Comment: @KevinL I see no difference in the table of contents with and without the code about the abstract.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't change the table of contents in the minimal example, but it is in my actual document for some reason.  I will have to see if I can figure out what the difference is between the two.  Thanks again!