# How change the size of title?

Tags: titles

i need change the size the 'abstract', only the title must affect the content must remain intact, 
I want a letter size 20

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}    
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}


\begin{abstract}
El principal mecanthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis intro
\end{abstract}
\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try just `\chapter*{\protect\Large ABSTRACT}` without the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands there.

Comment: Off topic: Why don't you use `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}` and do some settings there?

Comment: @JouleV by the margins and the title space with the content

Comment: Of course, that is why I said "do some settings there". I don't consider an abstract as a chapter in a book.

Comment: @x-rw You should have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151583/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-abstract.

Comment: @JouleV 
please help me I'm too new with latex, I just get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lmodern,lipsum}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{%
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries SECCI\'ON RESUMEN}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but 
What is the meaning of  24?

Comment: @x-rw: `\fontsize{<size>}{<baseline skip>}` sets both the font `<size>` and the skip between the baseline of successive lines (called the `<baseline skip>`). `\fontsize{20}{24}` sets a `20pt` font size with a slightly (20%, `24pt`) larger skip between baselines. It's not really necessary here since you're only setting a single "header"/title and therefore won't have multiple lines of text that could interfere with one another. See, for example, this [minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/KxLM5WJr) that yields [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4uTH.png).

Comment: yes it's ok, and how would I change if I want to use 'large', 'Large', 'LARGE'